# What is meant by "batches" in the context of SQL Server and ADO.NET?

Tags: .net, sql-server, ado.net

While looking for information about Multiple Active Result Sets(MARS) on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cfa084cz%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Thing which confuses me is usage of word "Batched" in following statement.

`Multiple Active Result Sets (MARS) is a feature that allows the execution of multiple batches on a single connection. In previous versions, only one batch could be executed at a time against a single connection. Executing multiple batches with MARS does not imply simultaneous execution of operations.`

On another website([this one](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/sudhi.pro/multiple-active-result-sets-mars/)) I found that `MARS` helps to execute multiple queries without closing single connection. Question is how this "batches" thing fits in here & what does this mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A batch is a SQL string that you send for execution to SQL Server. It can contain multiple statements. Every time you call `SqlCommand.Execute*` you send a single batch.

Answer (score 1):

batches in normally related to SQL. It is a set of a set of actions that are to be performed. Like if you have thousands of row that are to be inserted into a database you would create a batch and have it scheduled to run at night time.